# "I look for a place where I be free" — subjunctive or just bad English?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I'd like to know whether the phrase "where I be" is grammatically incorrect or whether it is correct if in the subjunctive mood. If it is in the subjunctive mood, what exactly would it mean?

The entire example sentence is:

> I look for a place where I be free.

Comment: You need to give the entire sentence for complete context. (Although I can't think of a sentence where "...where I be..." would be correct, it might be.)

Comment: "I look for a place where I be free". thanks

Comment: is this just bad english??

Comment: As an expert of subjunctive, I would say that that sentence doesn't make sense even considering "be" as a grammatically correct subjunctive. As far as I know, in that case, you should follow the rules governing the so-called non-finite clauses and, so, you should say "I look for a place where being free" or "I'm looking for a place where being free", I guess.

Comment: @Carlo_R. that does not look syntactically correct either.

Comment: I look for a place where I can be free or where I'll be free. _Where I be free_ is not correct English, but there are regions where they use "I be" for "I'll be"

Comment: **be**: "In 13c. it took the place of the infinitive, participle and imperative forms of am/was. Later its plural forms (we beth, ye ben, they be) became standard in Middle English and it made inroads into the singular (I be, thou beest, he beth), but forms of are claimed this turf in the 1500s and replaced be in the plural." http://etymonline.com/?term=be Today this construction is considered *archaic* or alternately, literary usage.

Comment: @Kris, why don't you write that as an answer?

Comment: "Don't tell her where I be!" Thomas Hardy: *Tess of the D'Urbervilles* :)

Comment: “I look for a place where I be free” is _highly poetic_ and quite _archaic_, but I would label it as a proper use of the subjunctive. The verbal notion here, ‘be free’, is a hypothetical situation conditioned by the (uncertain) finding of the place being sought, and the subjunctive emphasises this uncertainty. In other words, “where I be” is equivalent to “where I may be” here.

Comment: Or you could recast the sentence and say, "I look for a place where I, being free, could lay down roots anywhere I choose."

Answer (score 2):

"Where I be" can be used in conjunction with an auxiliary verb. I would suggest never using the phrase on its lonesome as "be" should be replaced with "am." Instead, inserting "would," "should," or "could" into the phrase can be used in a wide variety of situations.

> Hawaii is where I would/should/could be right now.

"Would" expresses a wish or a desire. "Should" expresses a sense of longing. Finally, "could" expresses a sense of possibility.

Comment: That is Modern English.